# How to get the id value in data-list on change the values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Here i am using data-list,bangalore is default selected so that time i can get the id value but when ever change values i am not able to get id values like suppose user want change insteed of bangalore , that time i want to take the value , how can do this ?

```js
var city_id = $('#cities option[value="' + $('#cityName').val() + '"]').data('id');
    console.log(city_id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input list="cities" value="Bangalore" class="form-control cities" name="cityName" id="cityName" style="border-radius:0px;height: 36px;">
<datalist id="cities">
<option data-id="1" value="Bangalore">
 <option data-id="2" value="Chennai">
<option data-id="3" value="Trichy">
</datalist>
```

Comment: Why are you using ids? Why not just get the value?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but you can add a `.change.` to `#cityName` and put your existing js code in the event handler.  This will give you the new city when it changes, but "changes" may not be what you're after `$("#cityName").change(function() {`

Comment: @minseong the value is the text, OP is trying to get the matching record id (not html `id=`), eg to save in a form

Comment: @freedomn-m but why? Just have an array of all the values, then `indexOf`. Idk, it's just weird to me. Why not make the values the numbers and then label them?

Comment: @minseong I can't speak for this case, only related cases where this would be the case - *most likely* the `data-id` is from a **DB identity column**.  In this *derived* case, it's 1,2,3 but could just as easily be 792,153,92.  In which case you couldn't use indexOf or some other "automatic" method to get the **data** id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("#cityName").change(function() {

  var city_id = $('#cities option[value="' + $('#cityName').val() + '"]').data('id');
  console.log(city_id);
}).change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input list="cities" value="Bangalore" class="form-control cities" name="cityName" id="cityName" style="border-radius:0px;height: 36px;">
<datalist id="cities">
  <option data-id="1" value="Bangalore">
    <option data-id="2" value="Chennai">
      <option data-id="3" value="Trichy">
</datalist>
```

Put it on change event

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for an onchange event with jQuery's [.change](https://api.jquery.com/change/):

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>` elements.

```js
$("#cityName").change(function () {
  var city_id = $('#cities option[value="' + $('#cityName').val() + '"]').data('id');
  alert(city_id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input list="cities" value="Bangalore" class="form-control cities" name="cityName" id="cityName" style="border-radius:0px;height: 36px;">
<datalist id="cities">
    <option data-id="1" value="Bangalore">
    <option data-id="2" value="Chennai">
    <option data-id="3" value="Trichy">
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the JS Part below instead of yours. this sould do the trick :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function getCityID() {
      var city_id = $('#cities option[value="' + $('#cityName').val() + '"]').data('id');
      console.log(city_id);
    }
    $("#cityName").on("change", getCityID);
    getCityID();
});
```

---

This part executes on change: `$("#cityName").on("change", getCityID);`

And this on load (to initialize): `getCityID();`

> Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3rb4h468/